# Indicative imperfect passive reflexive verb for "... is used..."

Tags: verbos, conjugación, pretérito-imperfecto, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

The sentence I'm trying to write in English:

> There even is a second *imperfect* within the subjunctive mode, but it's a bit archaic and mostly **used** in literary contexts.

The verb of interest here is written in bold. Here's my attempt at the sentence in Spanish.

> Hay hasta un imperfecto segunda dentro de subjuntivo modo, pero es un poco arcaico y es **se usaba** principalmente en contextos literarios.

I'm thinking imperfect because in English, the verb is in the past tense, and it is describing a habitual act (kinda). As in, this isn't some specific thing that happened, but a thing that happens. It's not really habitual, but I couldn't think of a better conjugation. I'm thinking passive reflexive, because *it* isn't used, but *being used*. Not sure if I've grasped the passive reflexive properly though.

Comment: segundo imperfecto. What ever are you referring to?

Comment: I think what is meant are the 2 forms of the Imperfect Subjunctive e.g. Hablara/Hablase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree with your analysis of your English sentence.  In the phrase "mostly used in literary contexts", the word "used" is not a past tense.  It is present tense, passive voice.

Accordingly, the Spanish would be "se usa" and not what you have.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that present tense verbs used in the passive voice gained the same suffix as verbs in the past tense. Considering English is my closest reference to Spanish, I should probably learn a bit more English grammar before trying to learn Spanish grammar.

Comment: @A.Kvåle a clue is the fact that the sentence said _it is a bit archaic_ and not _was a bit archaic_. So the sentence might have continued _and is mostly used in_. Nice catch by Walter here too.

Comment: The full present passive would be "is used".  The word "is" can be omitted in a context like this one.